# How would I get the last N quarters?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How would I get the last N quarters? I would like to extract the data that contains the last 5 quarters (including the current quarter).

Below is a SQL is just grouping the milestone to show how many unique data points there are. In these milestones, they contain multiple rows/data.

```
SELECT LEFT(MILESTONE,7) AS MILESTONE2
FROM XXXTable 
WHERE MILESTONE LIKE '%M0'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY MILESTONE2 DESC
```

MILESTONE2

```
2020_Q4
2020_Q3
2020_Q2
2020_Q1
2019_Q4
2019_Q3
2019_Q2
2019_Q1
2018_Q4
2018_Q3
```

Comment: Please provide example of input data and expected output/result. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by LEFT(MILESTONE, 7) desc) as seqnum
      from XXXTable 
      where MILESTONE like '%M0'
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5
```